# Firebase Cloud Functions: check for revoked token

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm attempting to make an administration role within firebase using claims and check the role in `onCall` methods within the Cloud Functions environment. I was under the assumption that the `context.auth.token` would be verified, but it seems that a user, when changed from admin to regular user (or any other edit on a user, which revokes the auth token using `admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(uid)`) doesn't actually revoke the rights immediately, OR the token isn't verified on the subsequent onCall by the edited user:

```js
export const someFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const isAdmin = context.auth?.token.admin === true
  ...
}):
```

results in isAdmin still being true after revocation of the token on the user (and setting admin to false).

What would be the appropriate way to check this? I tried validating `context.instanceIdToken` manually, but it isn't (always) set. All calls I make are logged in.

Any pointers would be appreciated. As you can understand, 'revoking admin access' is usually an action that should be immediate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `admin` in your token is a custom claim, which the client sends to the Cloud Function with each request as part of its ID token. The ID token on the client is refreshed once per hour. So after you add/remove the custom claim, it may take up to an hour before the client gets it, and passes it along to Cloud Functions.

*When an ID token is minted, it gets an expiration timestamp. Until that timestamp has passed, the ID token is assumed to be valid. Since the ID tokens of Firebase are typically valid for one hour, they can still be used for up to an hour after you make changes to the underlying user profile.*

You can force the client to refresh its ID token before that, by calling the `getIDToken(true)` API ([Android link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getIdToken(boolean)), but other platforms have a similar API). Also see the section in the documentation on [propagating custom claims to the client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client). But this depends on the client, so isn't good enough for security.

To ensure that updated tokens can no longer be used, you'll want to create a list of such "revoked" tokens. Then have your Cloud Function check against the list of revoked tokens, and reject the request if the token has been invalidated there. See for an example of this the example in the Firebase documentation on [detecting ID token revocation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation).

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up! I would assume from the docs saying "The Firebase Admin SDK provides the ability to revoke refresh tokens for a specified user. In addition, an API to check for ID token revocation is also made available." that such a think should be possible out of the box, but I guess I'll have to implement your suggestion!

Comment: That API does exist, and is shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation_in_the_sdk. But I've never used it myself, due to the reasons explained in the section right above it.

Comment: Yes I tried that, with `context.instanceIdToken`, as described in my initial question. However, I can't rely on the instanceIdToken to be set. I don't know why, but it's sometimes undefined inside the onCall of the Cloud Function.

Comment: I'd also expect it to be set **if** there is an authenticated user in the calling app. When you don't get an ID token, I'd assume it's a call from an unauthenticated client.

Comment: I would so as well! The user is definitely authenticated though (I only have entrypoints to the method in the calling client app if the user is logged). The context.auth is properly filled, so that already shows the user is authenticated, right?

Comment: Yeah. I'd assume that is actually populated from the ID token, so don't know how ID token would not be set in that case.

Comment: I'll do an additional test to verify it, will get back here. Until then your answer fixes the issue in a different way, thanks!